# Фильтрация повторяющихся друг за другом символов из String java

Tags: java, алгоритм, строки, стек

Нужен метод для фильтрации строки от повторяющихся подряд четное число раз элементов.

Слева то, что приходит в метод, а справа то что должно получиться.

```
/*
 * "" -> ""
 * "a" -> "a"
 * "aa" -> ""
 * "aaa" -> "a"
 * "abba" -> ""
 * "abcba" -> "abcba"
 * "abbccddef" -> "aef"
 */
```

Думаю, это нужно сделать через стек и проверять у него текущий элемент с последним у в его стеке.

В коде я стою на этом месте:

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T t = new T();
        System.out.println(t.str(""));
        System.out.println(t.str("a"));
        System.out.println(t.str("aa"));
        System.out.println(t.str("aaa"));
        System.out.println(t.str("abba"));
        System.out.println(t.str("abcba"));
        System.out.println(t.str("abbccddef"));
    }

    private String str(String value) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        Stack<Character> stack2 = new Stack<>();
        if (value.equals("") || value.length() == 1) {
            return value;
        }
        char[] array = value.toCharArray();
        for (char c : array) {
            stack.push(c);
        }
        for (char c : stack) {
```

Вылезает ошибка, что стек 2 пустой. Вообще можно одним стеком обойтись, но все равно упираюсь в непонимание, как повторно сделать проверку на одинаковые символы. См. `abba - > ""`. Т.е. сначала мы убираем `bb`, а вторым проходом убираем `aa`.

```
            char end = stack2.peek();
            if (c != end) {
                stack2.push(c);
            }
        }
        return stack2.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ИМХО, для вашей задачи стек вообще не нужен. Просто проверяйте в вашем цикле - равен текущий символ предыдущему или нет, если не равен - добавляйте предыдущий в результирующую строку, если равен - пропускайте его. В качестве результирующего буфера, можно использовать StringBuffer. В общем, задача на конечный автомат.

Comment: ну вот как то не очень зоходит у меня в воображении как это будет работать. вот есть 1221 допустим. стали проверять, и следующая строка будет 121 а должно стать 11 а затем "".

Comment: Чтобы не получить 121 добавьте счётчик и условие. Если нужна многопроходная проверка (что уже сложно назвать "фильтрация", я то думал вам в один проход всё надо проверить) - то это уже посложнее. Есть ещё вариант делать ReplaceAll с регуляркой на два одинаковых символа (меняя их на ""), до тех пор пока length меняется. (делать это в бесконечном цикле)

Comment: спасибо. буду думать над первым вариантом т.к. в условии указано что сложность должна быть O(N)

Comment: одного стека достаточно должно быть. Для каждого символа в строке сравниваете его с вершиной стека. Если они совпадают, удаляете символ с вершины, иначе добавляете туда текущий символ. Для строки "abba" стек будет меняться так: "a", "ab", "a", "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // исходная строка
        String str;
        // итоговая строка
        String res = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // вводим исходную строку
        str = sc.nextLine();
        // используем для нее StringBuffer
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);
        // подсчитаем длину строки
        int x = sb.length();

        // начинаем поочередно перебирать каждый элемент
        // и сравнивать его со всеми следующими
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            int s = 1; // счетчик уникальности элемента
            for (int j = i + 1; j < x; j++) {
                // если элементы совпадают
                if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(j)) {
                    // удаляем 2-ой такой же элемент
                    sb.deleteCharAt(j);
                    s++; // увеличиваем счетчик уникальности
                    x--; // уменьшаем показатель длины строки
                }
            }
            // после того как мы сравнил I элемент со всеми 
            // остальными проверяем четный ли он, и если "да"
            if (s % 2 != 0) {
                // добавляем его в итоговую строку
                res += sb.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        // выводим итоговую строку на экран
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```